# Calculating monthly compounded interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

To solve the problem

> How long does it take for an investment to double in
>   value if it is invested at 8% compounded monthly?

I figured like this:
$$2P = P(1 + 0.08)^t$$ 
where $P$ is an arbitrary principle investment and $t$ is the time in months. I then solved with logs, 
$$\log_{1.08}2 = t \approx 9.006$$
However, the back of the book gives $t \approx 104.28$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Compounded *monthly* matters...

Comment: More than likely, 8% is supposed to be the annual interest rate, so the monthly rate is one-twelfth of 8%. Then you would solve $2P = P(1 + \frac{0.08}{12})^t$. The question should have made that clear.

Answer (score 2):

You have set up the wrong formula for monthly compounded interest. It should be

$$
2P = P\left(1 + \frac{0.08}{12}\right)^{t}
$$

where $t$ is in months.

Note that the answer you have is for $t$ **in years**, which is about 108 months, so its not *as* wrong as it might first look (it's still incorrect though).

Answer (score 1):

The book's answer makes sense if the interest is not 8% *per month*, but 8% "per annum", or more precisely $\frac8{12}$% per month.

(I'm getting 104.32 rather than 104.28 under that assumption, but that may just be a rounding issue).